# Jenkins won't run PHPUunit - Permission denied

Tags: java, symfony, ant, jenkins, phpunit

I have installed PHPUnit via Composer and when I try to run PHPUnit as an Ant task it fails.

The Task:

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
    <exec executable="bin/phpunit" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-c" />
        <arg path="${basedir}/app/phpunit.xml.dist" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

The error:
phpunit:

> BUILD FAILED
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/build.xml:23: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run      >program “bin/phpunit”: error=13, Permission denied
>   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
>   ........

I have tried to implement CI server for a Symfony2 project on Ubuntu 12.04. Any idea what may be happening?

Comment: Did you run the command using `sudo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions for executing `phpunit` program. Please try using `sudo` to execute your script.

Note : Try modifying the permissions of `phpunit` installation directory using `chmod` like

`chmod 777`

Comment: It's work, I add two rules to ant script before run tests <chmod file="${basedir}/bin/phpunit" perm="ugo+x"/> / <chmod file="${basedir}/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" perm="ugo+x"/> Thanks

Comment: Great, Thanks for the reponse on how you solved it :)